# Word wrapping for a UILabel not created in IB?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I am trying to create a `UILabel` entirely in code, not IB.

I want the x,y corner position and the width to be fixed, but the height to vary according to how much text is being presented, and the text to wrap and be centered. The text is populated from elsewhere. (It won't be normally more than 2 lines long though)

I have got this far, but not sure how to make the height variable and to get the text to wrap:

```
instructLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(ScreenWidth/2-350, ScreenHeight-ScreenHeight*0.2, 700, 50)) // Guess I don't want the 50 height here though?
instructLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

instructLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 700 // does this conflict with above or override?
instructLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
instructLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

instructLabel.text = ""
instructLabel.font = FontSmall
instructLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.addSubview(instructLabel)
```

Comment: Do you want to use AutoLayout?

Comment: You need to set `instructionLabel.numberOfLines=0` to allow it to grow. The default value is 1, which will cause truncation rather than new lines. Or set it to a maximum number of lines you want. I would be using constraints for all this and auto layout.

Comment: Hi Bannings - I want to try and do it in code if possible!

Comment: many thanks Rory. works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

you should use `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMidY` constants instead of calculating ScreenWidth and ScreenHeight values.

```
instructLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame),self.view.frame,self.view.frame))
```

Comment: even though the class is of type UIView it doesn't have a member named 'view'

Comment: self.bounds might be valid for UIView